# Acumatica automation notifications on a custom DAC

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to setup automation notifications on a custom DAC, not an exiting one.

I couldn't found any sources which explains step by step how to do that.

So I've a custom DAC EAAsset and custom graph AssetEntry. Exactly what is the  correct way to make a standart notifications button visible?  And then what steps are required to make it work?

[image]

Comment: Did you add a NoteID to your BLC's  main DAC?

Comment: Yes I have added a NoteID to my main DAC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a hidden property called `NotifyIndicator`, which once set to **true** on the top-level form will show the Notifications button in the top-right corner of the screen:

```
<asp:Content ID="cont2" ContentPlaceHolderID="phF" Runat="Server">
    <px:PXFormView ID="form" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" ... NotifyIndicator="True" >
        <Template>
            ...
        </Template>
    </px:PXFormView>
</asp:Content>
```